# Create JSON Array from List<Object> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is a basic Java question I think that I can't work out how to get around.

I get data from Google Analytics API and store the rows in my database as a string as a JSONArray

```
[["New Zealand","Auckland","1640","8.795731707317072","516.4469512195122"],["New Zealand","Wellington","1314","8.428462709284627","580.3302891933029"]]
```

For Google Maps I need a JSON Array:

```
function drawMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', 'Popularity'],
        ['New York', 200],
        ['Boston', 300],
        ['Miami', 400],
        ['Chicago', 500],
        ['Los Angeles', 600],
        ['Houston', 700]
      ]);
```

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap

I need to change my data, by parsing it and iterating through it to remove the first (i.e. "New Zealand") and last variable from each object - I also need to add the headers i.e. ['City', 'Popularity']

Using GSonBuilder I can create JSON

```
[{"city":"Wellington","sessions":"1314","viewsPerSessions":"8.428462709284627","avgDuration":"8.428462709284627"},{"city":"Christchurch","sessions":"432","viewsPerSessions":"10.127314814814815","avgDuration":"10.127314814814815"}]
```

How do I turn that into a JSON Array?

Comment: It is JSON!, anyway, what's your question? you have data and a method you want to call, what's the problem? Explain better your problem

Comment: I need to change my data, by parsing it and iterating through it to remove the first (i.e. "New Zealand") and last variable from each object - I also need to add the headers i.e. ['City', 'Popularity']

Comment: Ok, your question it's "how to parse this info"? if yes, please edit your question to explain better your question, not on comments. If this is your problem i will help you to parse a JSON file

Comment: I can already parse it I'm using JSONSerializer. This isn't the problem.. it's recreating the JSON that's correct for Google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the JSON parse of Android. With this you can get what you want.

Try this:

```
JSONArray js_data = [["New Zealand","Auckland","1640","8.795731707317072","516.4469512195122"],["New Zealand","Wellington","1314","8.428462709284627","580.3302891933029"]];
int lenght = js_data.length();
JSONArray city;
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    //get each city
    city = js_data.getJSONArray(i);
    String nameCity = city.getString(0);
    String pop = city.getString(4);
    //Create a object JSON or whatever you want with this data
    JSONArray js_array = new JSONArray();       
    js_array.put(city); js_array.put(pop);
    //And put on a list
    js_map.put(js_array);
}
```

This is a basic java coding.
Hope it's helps.